# django-background-tasks not working with django-hosts

Tags: django, django-hosts

django-background-tasks package does not work when django-hosts package is configured.

My background task function looks something like this:

```
@staticmethod
@background(queue="text")
def sendMessage(phone_number, message):
```

I am running this function on a specific queue.

Also background task command is running too.

```
python3 manage.py process_tasks --queue text
```

My hosts configuration works properly. But not background tasks. When I remove hosts configuration background task function executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `DEFAULT_HOST` setting? Since there's no HTTP request in the CLI/background task, there's no other way to detect the HOST, which could be the cause of your errors.

Also, posting an actual error message with your question would be useful.

> Set the DEFAULT_HOST setting to the name of the host pattern you want to refer to as the default pattern. It'll be used if no other pattern matches or you don't give a name to the host_url template tag.

Comment: Yes, I did set DEFAULT_HOST in my settings. There are no errors in when I make the api call. Just the background task is not getting triggered.